# How to use snoop WPF for UI Automation

Tags: wpf, ui-automation, snoop

I am trying to automate an app using AutomationElement or TestWhite/FlaUI, the problem is snoopWPF seems the only one that is able to see the elements inside the window due to its injection feature (spy++ or inspect.exe do not see the visualtree).

Is it possible to use snoop code to automate a button click on a windows? any examples? thanks

Comment: You might consider automation specific projects like https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver

Comment: tried it does not work, the only one seems to work now is telerik testing framework

Comment: What kind of UI Controls do you use? The controls need to support Microsoft UIA in so that tools like FlaUI can work. If they do not support it, some can enable it (like DevExpress Controls). If this was just not implemented (which is very bad as then all accessibility features do not work as well), you need other tools which use the VisualStree or images to automate it.